# Entering session variables into database of logged in user and linking tables to get username id

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to php but have a pretty basic understanding of it.  I have just figured out how to create a session. Once a customer finishes an order I am trying to get basic information of the order into the "order table" of database for that specific logged in username. I have 2 tables in this database.

Customers:  which has 4 columns.  id | username | password | url

Orders: has 4 columns.  id | address | user_id | cost |

How to I write a query that gets the logged in users ID from "customers" and INSERTS that id along with the session variables into the "orders" table? Hopefully someone can help!

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO orders (address, user_id) VALUES $name WHERE id = " . 
$_SESSION['username']['id']);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

After trying to figure it out from tutorials and such this is the best I could come up with but I couldn't find anything that showed how to grab the id from the logged in user and insert into another table along with session variable data.  Please help?

**EDIT**
Not sure if this is the start of the problem but I need to know how to start a session defining what the logged in users id is in the first place.  Is there a way to define the id into the existing session after login is validated?  Here is the login script.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();


//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or 
die(mysql_error()); 

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$login = clean($_POST['login']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($login == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login-form.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE login='$login' AND password='".($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);



//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];

        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_login'] = $member['login'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_password'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();


        header("location: fullreport100_member_checkout.php");
        exit(); 
    }else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: login-failed.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

Comment: When you `echo $_SESSION['username']['id']);` , can u c the result?

Comment: No I can't.  So I guess that means I have not defined the session id of the user?  Maybe I got a little ahead of myself and am not ready yet to insert into database yet.  Any advice on how to get the database id of logged in user after login validation?  I have tried everything.  Let me know if I should post the login.php script for you.  @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for INSERT:

```
   INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
     VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Therefor when you insert, you need to you need to do something like this:

```
$address = 'address 1';
$user_id = 5;
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO orders (address, user_id) VALUES ('". $address . "', " . $user_id . ")");
```

I am also not use if this is correct syntax (I never used it) : `$_SESSION['username']['id']` (I assume this is multi-dim array in session)

If you have classed defined, you need to use `$_SESSION['username']->id`